# Android checkbox to be like in iOs

Tags: android, checkbox, styles

I want to have the checkboxes in my app to be like in iOs where its in a "pressed" and "not-pressed" button state instead of checked box.

I attached and image from http://jquerymobile.com/ which can show to the concept.
[image]

any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? Any written code on the subject? Also a simple google search will solve your problem.

Comment: You might consider linking to an annotated screenshot showing what you are referring to.

Comment: First of all, iOS does not have have check boxes.  The behavior you're describing is called a button or are you referring to a slider switch?

Comment: I don't have a code sample, I'm looking for samples with nicer UI